# pagingtoolbar in ExtJs: all the data is displayed at once when I want it to be separated in different pages

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I'm having a problem trying to add a toolbar and paging to my grid that provide search results. I want to add that because some searches bring up hundreds of items so I want to separate them in different pages and only show 25 of them by page.

My problem is that while the toolbar is okay and the different pages are here, the results still show up all at once every page. Like for exemple if a search brings you 200 results, there will be 8 pages (like it should), but each pages would show you the 200 items instead of only 25. I followed strictly (i think) the senchadoc article on the subject, so if anybody could help me that would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance. Here's my code :

```
panelResult: function() {
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        id:'userBeaconList',
        storeId:'userBeaconList',
        autoLoad: false,
        pageSize: 25,
        fields:[//BLABLABLA],
        data: //MyData,
        proxy: { 
            type: 'memory',
            reader: { type: 'json', root: 'items' } 
        }
    });     

        // specify segment of data you want to load using params
        store.load({
            params:{
                start:0,
                limit: 25,
            }
        });     

        return Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: SarsatConf.listBeaconTitle,
            margin : '10 0 0 0',
            anchor: '100%' ,
            store: store,
            columns: [ //BLABLABLA],
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar', 
                store: store,   
                dock: 'bottom',
                displayInfo: true
            }],  
        });
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration seems OK. That's probably your server that is not respecting the `limit` and `start` params...

Another option would be to load the data from the server once, and put them into a memory proxy that will emulate paging on the client side.

Comment: Hum, that's what I was thinking too. Would that solution be ok : http://blog.jardalu.com/2013/6/21/grid-paging-extjs-sencha ?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. Except that contrarily to what the author says, the paging memory does support paging with its [`enablePaging`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Memory-cfg-enablePaging) option. I've updated [his fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TE4ah/80/) to illustrate this.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this tomorrow and get back here with the results.

Comment: You're right, it seems the `enablePaging` option was added in 4.2. However, there was an ux doing the same thing in 4.1: [`Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy). I've updated [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TE4ah/82/) again to use 4.1.0, and PagingMemoryProxy.

Comment: So it works fine now on the paging, but when I sort the grid, it only sorts the data on the current page, not all the data.

EDIT : Nevermind, I added "remoteSort: true" to the store and now it works!